# Tools available to aggregate all project related information in one place

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven-based Java webapp that has bunch of unit tests, integration tests, code coverage reports etc and some more technical details.

I would like generate project information which would contain all the above information aggregated in one place so that it could be seen by others.

What's are some of the tools available in order to achieve this?

Comment: You mean you want/need a tool that helps you checking the results of the execution of your tests to review the metrics for your project or something like that?

Comment: Yes, I need a tool where I could show all the unit and integration test results in a centralized place

Comment: Ever taken a look into Maven site generation which can created reports about those things ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes looked into mvn site generation but not sure how to deploy the site to remote server and not sure if I can specify project roadmap, current open issues, technical details such as tools and technologies used for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote server upload can be done either via [http/dav/scp](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/adding-deploy-protocol.html) etc.

You can maintain a roadmap via [markdown/apt](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html) or [other formats](https://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/index.html).

Current open issues (may be jira) via [maven-changes-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/) ?

Technical details such as tools etc. can be documented by the above as well?

Unit tests results can be done via usual maven site generation ([surefire reporting](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/)) Code coverage via [cobertura](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) the old way or via [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html).

Comment: I already have  a WAMP server installed and running on another machine Windows machine. Can I deploy the site to it? If yes, then can you please provide me some online tutorial or a working example? I googled around but all I could find were some webdav examples and that too very old.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/wagon/ will give you things for webdav ....If you like to deploy via scp you can take a look at wagon as well. Apart from that i would suggest to start using a repository manager like Nexus which contains a site location by default which would make it simpler.